# Triple integral over a portion of a ball

Tags: integration, analysis

I would like to know if the answer to the following integral is right or wrong: using spherical coordinates compute 
$$
\iiint_{A} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+x^2}} \, dxdydz
$$
where
$A=\left \{ (x,y,z): 1 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2z \right \}$. My solution is:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{1}^{2 \cos \varphi} \frac{1}{\rho} \cdot \rho^2 \sin \varphi \, d \rho d\varphi d\theta= ...=\frac{2}{3}\pi
$$
the book's answer would be $\frac{\pi}{3}$, so who's wrong?

Comment: That integral is over a portion of a *ball*, not a sphere. On a sphere, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ would be constant.

Comment: @JohnHughes ok!

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me. I'm getting $2\pi/3$ too.